# How to initialize an array in a template class with a custom value?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

For example

```
template<size_t N>
class A
{
    array<int, N> m;
    static A const UNIT {1, 1, ...}; // repeated N times, 
                                     // but I can't because of currently unspecified N
}
```

How to initialize a template sized array with the custom value `1`?

Comment: Not sure, but if I see `...` in conjunction with templates, I start thinking of using variadic template parameter lists and unpacking. Don't know how to generate these though, using a non type template parameter giving their number.

Comment: fill does some work. But I don't know how to put it. may be with lambda???

Comment: Ah, well. Yes sure that does it. I was premising you were looking for a compile time solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fill function.
This works fine with a static const member, too.

```
template<size_t N>
class A {
    array<int, N> m;
    public:
    static A const unit;
    A() { m.fill(1); }
};

template<size_t N>
A<N> const A<N>::unit{};
```